# How to hide Load more button if less product on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using PHP with a prepared statement. I am fetching the data from the database and display on the page.

Now on page load, I have to display only four `li` and reset of the `li` should be displayed after a click on `load more` button

**Index**

```
<?php $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;?>
    <ul id="a-p-AllList">
      <?php while ($stmt->fetch()) {?>
      <li>
        <div class="a-product-content">
          <h3>
            <?php echo $subproduct_name?>
          </h3>
          <div class="a-heroCTA btn_pviewMore">
            <?php if (($category_id==3) || ($category_id==4)){?>
            <a href="assets/images/pdf/<?php echo $_GET['category'];?>/<?php echo $pdfname;?>" class="viewproductList" download><strong>Download PDF</strong> <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            <?php } else{?>
            <a href="product-view?key=<?php echo $id?>&category=<?php echo $slug ?>" class="viewproductList"><strong>View More</strong> <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            <?php }?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="loadMore" class="text-center">Load more</div>
    <?php } $stmt->close();?>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var init_item = 4;
  var items = "<?php echo $numberofrows; ?>";
  var shown = 4;
  $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + init_item + ')').show();//on page load displaying 4 li
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    shown = $('#a-p-AllList li:visible').length + 4;
    if (shown < items) {
      $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + shown + ')').show();
    } else {
      $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + items + ')').show();
      $('#loadMore').hide();
    }
  });

  // if (init_item>=4) {
  //  // alert('true');
  //    $('#loadMore').hide();
  // }

});
```

Above code is working if I have more then 4 products and load more button hide at the end if there is no product but If I have less then 4 products then load more button is still showing on the screen. I don't want to display load more button if I have less then 4 products on screen.

Comment: something like `if ( totalItems <= 4 ) { $('#loadMore').hide(); } ` ? where totaltems is the number of all the items coming from the db

Comment: @MihaiT, Where should I add this code? I tried at the end which is the comment

Comment: **FYI:** PHP has an [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which you might find "better" for your files.

Comment: well you should first know how many items come from the database. Do you ' know ' that ? if yes, store it in a variable and compare that to `4`. In the commented part you check `init_item` which is 4 against 4. It won't work.

Comment: Assuming we’re talking MySQLi here regarding the $stmt part - `<?php if($stmt->num_rows > 4): ?><div id="loadMore" class="text-center">Load more</div><?php endif; ?>`

Comment: @MihaiT, give  me 5 mins I am updating the index and script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jQuery/javaScript solution. You might be able to solve your problem in the `php` code. But i cannot help you with that. I am sure it's possible to check how many fetched products you have and display the `load more` button according to that. ( in php ).

You load all the items at once from the database, right ? And then you only show ( with `display: block` because that's what `.show()` does. ) 4 at once.

So by doing `$('#a-p-AllList li').length` you would get the total number of list items you have coming from the database.

What you should do is just compare `$('#a-p-AllList li').length` against `4` or whichever number you want.

My suggestion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var init_item = 4;
  var items = 16;
  var shown = 4;
  const totalItems = $('#a-p-AllList li').length;

  $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + init_item + ')').show();//on page load displaying 4 li

  if (totalItems <= 4 ) {  
     $('#loadMore').hide() 
  } else {
     $('#loadMore').click(function() {
       shown = $('#a-p-AllList li:visible').length + 4;
       if (shown < items) {
         $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + shown + ')').show();
       } else {
         $('#a-p-AllList li:lt(' + items + ')').show();
         $('#loadMore').hide();
       }
     });
   }

});
```

Comment: I updated the index and script. I added $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows; to get the total number of rows and added in script var items = "<?php echo $numberofrows; ?>";

Comment: well if you know in php how many fetched items you have, just add a condition and display the button according to that condition

Comment: Your explanation is awesome!.. I got your point. Give me some time to understand

Comment: @MithaiT, Thanks for the help. It's working for me.

Comment: @questionbank glad i could help :D

Answer (score 0):

#### you can check if condition for fetched products.

Products are less then 4 then you can hide load more button.